# JTessBoxEditor is not identifying the characters and making boxes

Tags: machine-learning, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to train my tesseract by making box characters in the images but the JTessBoxEditor is not recognising any characters. When running the command --> tesseract eng.arial.exp1.tiff eng.arial.exp1 batch.nochop makebox--> it is creating a box file on the same .tiff image but it I do not know how to edit the text file. Is there any reason the JTessBoxEditor is not recognising any characters? Is there any alternative training software or method.

I expected that each .tiff file will be boxed automatically. Since the .box files are being generated with tesseract, is there any way to precisely edit the .box file to feature the correct characters

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the box file, you can switch to Box Editor tab, open it, and start editing.

http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html

Answer (score 0):

jTessBoxEditor text boxing Problem:

It simply is a Java app that piggybacks on the Public domain Tesseract Engine available from Github. Gogle traineddata"a for Tesseract"to get to the training data for the many languages some generous folks have provided at Github.
URL: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/

Step 1:
For jTessBoxEditor( any version for that matter) to work you need at the least a language training data file from Github.
URL: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/

Go to that page an left click on the language (*.traineddata) link [i.e. for Hungarian = hun.traineddata for English eng.traineddata]. So look out for the three letters representing your language of choice.

Step 2:

Once you get to your language page you will be utterly lost as there is no data to download.  But there is a simple trick..... There is a small Active link Named "Raw" a quarter way down on the right-hand side of of the page just above the text line >
"View raw
(Sorry about that, but we can’t show files that are this big right now.)"

Just next to the word "RAW" there is an active download link . You can find it with a small icon a "Down Arrow with a tray". Mouse-over it and you can click to download the language data to your PC. If by chance the download does not work right click on the word "raw" and choose "Save Link As" and the download will activate to any folder on your PC. If you had gone to the hun.traineddata page you will be downloading the Hungarian trained data.

Step 3:

Now copy paste the *.traineddata file to your>
"?\jTessBoxEditor\tesseract-ocr\tessdata" folder where the default eng.traineddata file also resides. This step arms your jTessBoxEditor with the required tools to interpret a non English font.

Step 4;

After you have got you box file organized remember that you have to undergo long hours of tedious manual graphic work to help jTessBoxEditor to get each glyph matched to the correct Unicode number for that character or numeral and also manually adjust the X Y coordinates of the  enclosing red box its size width height on the tif file page of each glyph.

Conclusion:

Windows 3.1 had an excellent software OCR package that did a marvelous job with any Latin Text and it was easy to train to recognize any squiggle and allocate a Unicode to each. Using proprietory Font Generator one could also generate a Special font  with the Squiggles. It could be trained with Dingbats Windings or Handwritten text and diagrams etc.

said I Dias